# REINFORCE algorithm, help for the proof of the variance reduction by subtracting a baseline

Tags: variance, inequality, policy-gradient

I'm trying to find a proof or an approximate argument justifying that, in the REINFORCE algorithm, subtracting a baseline to the episode reward reduces the variance. I believe this proof can be done without the context of the algorithm since it's mostly about computing variance.

Formally, multiple sources such as this [article by Daniel Seita](https://danieltakeshi.github.io/2017/03/28/going-deeper-into-reinforcement-learning-fundamentals-of-policy-gradients/), or [those slides](http://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse-fa17/f17docs/lecture_4_policy_gradient.pdf), try to show the following (or close formulations) :

$$ \mathrm{Var}\bigg(\sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \nabla_{\theta}  \log \pi_{\theta}(a_t | s_t) \big) r(\tau)  \bigg) \geq  \mathrm{Var} \bigg(\sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \nabla_{\theta}  \log \pi_{\theta}(a_t | s_t) \big) ( r(\tau) - b(s_t)) \bigg).$$

With $\pi_{\theta}$ a probability distribution parameterized by a parameter $\theta$, $r(\tau)$ and $b(s_t)$ two scalars.
But something is already strange to me, We are considering the variance of a random vector, it should actually be a covariance matrix so how does the $\leq$ symbol makes sense in this context ? The two link I gave seems to treat the random vector as a random variable, for example, using the identity for random variable :

$$ \mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2.$$

Am I missing an argument justifying treating the random vector as a random variable ?

Comment: why do you think it's a vector?

Comment: because there's a gradient in the sum ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your doubt, for a while I also felt that why we are not using covariance as $\tau$ ($\tau := s_0,a_0,s_1,a_1,...,s_{T-1}$)  is random vector and not random variable.

Answer:

1. $X$ is not random vector but it is random variable in this case.

$\hspace{2em}$ As $X = \underbrace{\sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \nabla_\theta \log(a_t|s_t)r(\tau)}_\text{scalar}$

2. You have also mentioned that you think that taking a gradient should give us a vector. But when we take the gradient then we get the slope of that vector rather than the vector itself.